# Asynchron Errorhandling inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, error-handling, node-mysql

I am on server side Node.js and somehow caught up in the callbacks. I use the following function to insert data in the Table with the mysql pkg:

```
  connection.query('INSERT INTO tableName SET ?', post, function(err, result) 
  {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')
        {  }
      else
        { throw err; }
    }
  });
```

I want to log how many duplicate entries are there without stoping the loop which calls this above function by an $.each.

It says [here](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) that I have 3 possibilities: throw, callbacks and EventEmitter. Throwing won't work, since this stops everything. I tried it with callbacks, but because I am in the callback from the $.each I couldn't find away in the above scope. I didn't try with a static EventEmitter since I don't know how to return any value from an $.each selector, except the selected data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest everything in a closure and count the finished queries in the callback, so that you know when is the last query finished:

```
(function(){
  var errors = 0;
  var started = 0;
  var successful = 0;
  $.each(..., function(){
    started++;
    connection.query('INSERT INTO tableName SET ?', post, function(err, result) 
    {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')
          { errors++; }
        else
          { throw err; }
      } else { successful++;}
      if (started == successful + errors) {
         // all done
         console.log(errors + " errors occurred");
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks :) my brain got a little in the way i guess. This is working for my purpose since i only want to log this Counter out. Still if i would use this value to calculate something coming from outside the $.each. Would i always have to handle this, deep in the nested functions or is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean outside $.each?

Comment: It was just an example, another one would be:
When the async function of the last query is finished is there another way to write "Import Finished" then in this nested functon while counting to the end.

Comment: There might be, it's probably a good question, try to ask it as a separate question