# Waiting for data from async nested Functions within JQuery $.each in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, nested-function

this is a follow up question to [Asynchron Errorhandling inside $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246797/asynchron-errorhandling-inside-each). As mentioned in the comments there, i want to handle data after the last async job from a $.each loop.

So for instance:

```
  var errors = 0;
  var started = 0;
  var successful = 0;
  $.each(..., function(){
    started++;
    connection.query('INSERT INTO tableName SET ?', post, function(err, result) 
    {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY')
          { errors++; }
        else
          { throw err; }
      } else { successful++;}
      if (started == successful + errors) {
         // all done
         console.log(errors + " errors occurred");
      }
    });
  });
```

In this case everything logs out properly when the ***// all done*** comment is reached. But what if i want to use this data later on instead of just logging it out.

Is there a way to wait for this data outside of the $.each scope? Or do i always have to handle everything in the nested function?

Comment: I must admit I'm confused by what `$.each(..., function(){` does ... is `...` a placeholder for some real variable

Comment: Create array of promises in the loop. Resolve or reject each inside the query callback unless that `query()` method returns a promise itself. The problem with throwing error in a callback is there is nowhere to catch it but a promise chain lets you

Comment: Also, where does `post` come from? and why do you do a `$.each` where the function accepts no parameters ... looks like incomplete code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use promises instead

```
var promises = [];

$.each(..., function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {;
        connection.query('INSERT INTO tableName SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                resolve(err.code);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
    promises.push(promise);
});


var result = Promise.all(promises);
```

And then when you want to use the data, you do

```
result.then(function(data) {
    // use data array looking like ["result data", "result data", "ER_DUP_ENTRY" .. etc]
})
```

Comment: I was about to post a very similar answer, that was a bit tidier, by using `var result = Promise.all(jQuery.map(...`

Comment: I got this working. Still i could'nt figure it out in the end because i have another loop around this function and i wasn't able to make a sequential promise around this to figure out when every job has finished and i can close my msql connection.
In the end i made a bash script which calls the above function via node. This is pretty slow but it works and i can run this as a cron job